# Return places and addresses from Mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, axios, mapbox-gl

I am using the mapbox geocoder to return points based on search input. I would like my user to be able to type in raw addresses (e.g. 123 Elm St.) in addition to names of places (e.g. Starbucks). My function that returns results is here:

```
  geocodeThis(query) {
    const { homePoint } = this.state
    const accessToken = this.state.settings.accessToken
    axios.get('/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/'+query+'.json?access_token='+accessToken+'&proximity='+homePoint.geometry.coordinates[0]+','+homePoint.geometry.coordinates[1])
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({suggestions: response.data.features})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```